# Does AWS CPU and I/O performance vary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

While reading a benchmark about NoSQL Databases [[ref]](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/WP-Benchmarking-Top-NoSQL-Databases.pdf).

I found the following suspicious quote:

> In order to minimize the effect of AWS CPU and I/O variability, End
>   Point performed each test 3 times on 3 different days.

**p.s.** (End Point: is a company name)

My question now is: Does AWS CPU and I/O performance vary?

Comment: This is not an AWS-specific issue, it's a shared tenancy virtual hosting issue in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are variation in instance performance.  Search for the "aws noisy neighbor" problem for more information. There are also variation in the underlying hardware, which can also affect performance.  Some reports say that this is more likely the cause of differences that the noisy neighbor problem.

For I/O, you can now get EBS with guaranteed performance, so that is less of an issue.